# php check if a file is in a folder

Tags: php, file-upload, file-io, directory

I'm writing a script where I want to save a logo image. I create a "logo" folder for each user, e.g. user-data/user_1/logo/img007.png

If the user decides to upload a different image after a while I would like to delete the old one automatically, so that the webspace isn't unnecessarily wasted.

So far I decided not to rename the file during the upload process , therefore I can't use file_exists() in the folder as the script doesn't know the file name.

My question is, if there is a way in PHP to check if any file is in a specific folder and if so, to delete it.

If you think I've taken the wrong approach to this and should e.g. rename all the files to the same (which I think is a problem since I allow the 4 different common image formats) or save the file name of the "existing" file and let the script check for it, please tell me as well.

Comment: Look in the manual for `glob()` or `opendir()` / `readdir()` or `scandir()`.

Comment: why dont you rename the file? Makes things a lot easier if you know where you are looking for.

Comment: Not renaming files can also create security issues with your server.

Comment: so you think I should rename the files like logo.jpg (extension according to the original file) for example and then check in a loop if a file named logo with either .png, .gif, .jpg, .jpeg exists in the specific folder?

Comment: I would suggest using a naming function where the it would be the user's ID set as the image name. Then if that user decides to update the image, would retain its filename without having to go through 2-3 different processes (upload, delete, re-upload). Why can you not rename? Any special reason?

Comment: Please don't worry about wasting webspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a folder `user_logos/` and store each logo as `[user name]_logo.png`. You can obviously decide the extension. But I'd rather not have thousands of directories, each one containing only one file.

It would even better if you could create a random ID for each logo, such as `[random_id]_logo.png` and store the ID into the user table (in the database):

```
    User ID     |     User Name     |    Logo ID
```

and just load it from there.

Comment: Ok, so the approach would be to rename the file in a certain automated way, save the file name in the user database and check for that name with file_exists() if an update by the user occurs. I was hesitating with renaming because of the different possible extensions, but I guess if I completely save the file name with extension in the database, it should be no problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [readdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) or [scandir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php).